# Have Page Section Start UNDERNEATH Row of float:left divs

Tags: html, css, image

Here is the HTML page's code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>        
        <style type="text/css">
            div.image {
                float: left;   
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="image-gallery">
            <div class="image">
                <h3>Stack Overflow</h3>
                <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=41f6e13ade69" />
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <h3>Meta Stack Overflow</h3>
                <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflowmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=d65f9368620d" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <h1>Title</h1>

    </body>
</html>
```

And here is what the page then looks like:

[image]

What I want is for the page to look like this:

[image]

The problem is that the code underneath the `#image-gallery` is aligned *beside* the image gallery, since the `div`s inside are using the property `float: left`. As you can see in the images, the `Title` is not where I want it to be.

I am using the `float: left` property so that all of the images are beside each other. But I cannot use `padding` to force the `Title` into its proper place because the width of the page changes, which means the images might be stacked in more than 1 row.

How can I put the `Title` so it is always below the `#image-gallery`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should clear the floats, either with:

```
#image-gallery {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Or, use the micro clearfix hack.

```
#image-gallery:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Read this if you wish to learn more - http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: Thank you. I love the simplicity of this answer and only having to adjust the `#image-gallery` styling (as opposed to the other answer).

Comment: @mikeyaworski I suppose that you're new to the web dev area, since you have such high reps already, but without knowing the basic thing :P yes, clear floats is the direct answer to your question, there are many other way to make the similar layout, such as inline-block, css table, flexbox etc.

Comment: Haha yeah I'm a pretty young guy that's been an Android dev for a few years. I'm just now getting into web dev. I knew this would be a nooby question but I wasn't sure how to Google it.

Answer (score 1):

Use display:inline-block; instead of float, and a div or display:block; for the title.

Comment: Oh okay thanks for that. I tried `display: inline` earlier, but `display: inline-block` makes more sense. I'm an web dev noob.